# HTML select results in nil

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, select, devise

I have a model `User` with a string attribute `:location`. I'm trying to create a select from options field for it.

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <select name="user[location]" form="user[location]">
    <option value="Earth">Earth</option>
    <option value="Mars">Mars</option>
    <option value="Jupiter">Jupiter</option>
  </select>
  <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
<% end %>
```

But when I submit the form, the `User.last.location` is `nil`. I can get it to work if I use Rails `f.select`:

```
<%= f.select :location, options_for_select([['Earth'], ['Mars'], ['Jupiter']]) %>
```

Why isn't my html form working?

`User` is a Devise-generated model. Here's my application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :location
  end
end
```

The controller actions are built right into the gem files, so the controller derives from [here.](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb)

Comment: Is the issue that the selected location is not persisting on your user model? What does the rest of the form look like? Which endpoint does the form go to and what does that controller action look like?

Comment: What's the HTML code for the form?

Comment: @yez Yes, it's not persisting. I posted the full form, and clarified about the controller. I'm not sure what you mean by endpoint, though.

Comment: @arcyqwerty I posted the full form.

Comment: The name of your select box is `location` when it should be `user[location]` try that.

Comment: Yes, and `form="user[location]` isn't necessary if you're inside the form tags.

Comment: @yez I tried that, with the same result.

Comment: @arcyqwerty I'm not sure what you mean. I tried form="location" but that didn't work either.

Comment: `form=` attribute isn't needed at all since you're inside the `form` tag.  Try `name="user[last][location]"`.  Also, perhaps you should take the working `<%= f.select ...>` tag and compare the generated HTML

Comment: @arcyqwerty Huh, yeah I used the generated html and that worked, although I can't imagine why because the only difference is an id tag.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the html generated by the Rails form, and that worked.

```
<label for="user_location">Location</label>
<select id="user_location" name="user[location]">
  <option value="Earth">Earth</option>
  <option value="Mars">Mars</option>
  <option value="Jupiter">Jupiter</option>
</select>
```

I'm not sure why though...the only difference I see is the id tag.